# How to display the time and space your program takes in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It has been over a year since I'm using VSCode. Almost every day I search the web for ways to display the time taken (speed) and space taken(during execution) by my program. This info is very important. But unfortunately, I haven't found(or missed) a way to display these metrics. VSCode is cool to use and lightweight etc. etc., but these metrics were visible by default in some other IDEs (like codeblocks). Some extension or some setting I missed in the many articles I went through. If someone could help me out here, I'll be super grateful.

Thank you in advance

Comment: VSC is an editor, your programs are not run IN VSC, to get timing use the OS/shell way to time the execution and `ps` to see the space usages

Comment: @rioV8 Could you kindly guide me through that?

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ''' 
       Example code shows to display 
       the Time and Space taking of the program(creating N_gram language model)
    '''

    import os, psutil, time
    start = time.time()
    m = create_ngram_model(3, '/content/train_corpus.txt')  # Replace withyour custom function
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print('Memory usage in Mega Bytes: ', process.memory_info().rss/(1024**2))  # in bytes 
    print(f'Time Taken: {time.time() - start}')
```

You can add this `psutil.Process(os.getpid())` at any function(at **main** thread to see entire memory usage of the program) that you wish to see the status by`process.memory_info().rss` in the running time Memory usage:  0.5774040222167969. Also check this code for to know the program runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is this a python code? If yes, how will it work for programs in other languages?